# How to get corresponding Byte code of java MethodDeclaration

Tags: java, bytecode, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to get the byte code for a java method signature given MethodDeclaration object. I'm parsing the java class using Eclipse jdt and iterating over the MethodDeclaration like the following:

```
private static void processJavaFile(String javaFilePath) {
    List<MethodDeclaration> methodDeclarations = new ArrayList<MethodDeclaration>();
    FileInputStream reader = null;
    try {
        File javaFile = new File(javaFilePath);
        reader = new FileInputStream(javaFile);

        byte[] bs = new byte[reader.available()];
        reader.read(bs, 0, reader.available());
        String javaContent = new String(bs);

        CompilationUnit unit = ASTUtil.getCompilationUnit(javaContent, 4);
        MethodVisitor methodVisitor = new MethodVisitor();
        unit.accept(methodVisitor);
        methodDeclarations = methodVisitor.getMethods();
        for (MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration :methodDeclarations){
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // ???? I want to get the byte code of the method signature here ???? //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you've got the Eclipse source, you can look thru (manually) and try and find the compiler/ bytecode generator.  I assume it's a Visitor or similar, but there may require multiple steps to run before you can generate the bytecode.

Comment: What do you mean by bytecode of the signature?

Comment: @Antimony i mean some thing like that: 

java.lang.Object.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

Comment: Clean up your question: do you want to *generate* byte code as the title suggests or do want to *get* existing bytecode as your code suggest? You won’t get byte code from an AST representing the *source code*.

Comment: @Holger what I have is a MethodDelaration object and I need the corresponding byte code for the method signature

Comment: I can only repeat Antimony: what do your mean with “bytecode of the signature”?

Comment: @Holger I don't want the byte code of the whole method just the signature i.e for Object.eqauls the java method signature is: public boolean equals(object o) and the byte code will be: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

Comment: So why are you asking for “byte code” when you just want the signature? Ask for the signature if you want the signature. Or ask for “JVM internal signature” if you think “signature” is too ambiguous.

Comment: @Holger the original problem for me was to get info about each method including method name, return type, parameters types, parameter names and the byte code of the signature, I used BCEL but it doesn't have the parameter names so i had to reverse the process and parse the java file with AST to get the method declarations which have all data i need except the byte code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MethodDeclaration` instance is part of the *AST* representing the *syntax* of the source code. It requires resolving the type names found in the source code before you can create a signature for a method.

```
for (MethodDeclaration methodDeclaration :methodDeclarations){
  // the next line requires that the project is setup correctly
  IMethodBinding resolved = methodDeclaration.resolveBinding();
  // then you can create a method signature
  ITypeBinding[] pType = resolved.getParameterTypes();
  String[] pTypeName=new String[pType.length];
  for(int ix = 0; ix < pType.length; ix++)
    pTypeName[ix]=pType[ix].getBinaryName().replace('.', '/');
  String rTypeName=resolved.getReturnType().getBinaryName().replace('.', '/');
  //org.eclipse.jdt.core.Signature
  String signature = Signature.createMethodSignature(pTypeName, rTypeName);
  System.out.println(signature);
}
```

Comment: methodDeclaration.resolveBinding() returns null how ever i have already set resolveBindings & bindingsRecovery of the parser to true, any idea?

Comment: As said, the project needs to be set up. E.g. if you used `setEnvironment(String[], String[], String[], boolean)` you need also to use `setUnitName(String)` to provide a file name as you are not using an API method that specifies a File. That’s the minimum setup as far as I know.

Comment: But i'm not inside an Eclipse Plugin project, I'm inside Maven project and using using jdt as Maven dependency, any idea how to configure the jdt to resolve bindings?

Comment: Use the methods on the `ASTParser` instance. I gave you an example. With “project” I mean just the minimum information required for resolving, e.g. class path and source path. You can use empty arrays and use a value of `true` for `includeRunningVMBootclasspath` if your source code has no further dependencies.

Comment: it works now with some small modifications, I searched how to use    setEnvironment(String[], String[], String[], boolean) and found this example of how to use AST in stand alone application http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/trunk/testplugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.compiler/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/tests/dom/StandAloneASTParserTest.java